# is it possible to load image from asset by indicating DPI?

Tags: android, assets, dpi

I can load image from asset folder but it loads image based on current device DPI. is it possible to open an image with certain density?
for example, my device is xxhdpi but wants to open an image from asset based on xhdpi.

Thanks.

Comment: don't put the  drawable in xxhdpi. The OS will pick the xhpdi for you

Comment: It will automatically load image based on the dpi of your device

Comment: `wants to open an image from asset based on xhdpi.` NO. It wants to open the image from `drawable-xhdpi`

Comment: so the only way is to put those images inside drawable - xhdpi?

Comment: It's the preferred way. Or you can save them into the assets folder (or the raw folder) with a name like `some_name_xhdpi.png` and get them from there. But you also need some code to establish which dpi your device is running on